# through good times and bad

Tags: phrases

Here is the sentence I doubt:

> Thank you for sticking with me through good times and bad, in sickness and
> in health.

I know it's a reference to the marriage vow, but the "good times and bad" has "ones" or "times" omitted. Is that a commonly used phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very common to omit 'ones' when using two contrasting adjectives in this way, especially basic pairs like *good and bad, large and small, young and old*.